# Force views to only support landscape mode

Tags: orientation, modal-dialog, landscape

I want to only support landscape mode in my application. I have set the following:

1. Orientation for all view controllers in the application are set to Landscape. Some of the view controllers are in a storyboard while couple are not
2. The `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` method for all viewControllers are set to return TRUE for LandscapeLeft and LandscapeRight orientations and FALSE otherwise
3. Supported orientation in info.plist is set to landscape as well

Now when I run the application everything works as expected and the app starts in landscape model.

However under some conditions I have to throw a modal at the start of the application.
I open the model from the `rootviewcontroller` of my `UINavigationController` with the following code:

```
    AskInfoViewController *askInfo = [[AskInfoViewController alloc] init];
    [askInfo setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFormSheet];
    [askInfo setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];
    [self presentModalViewController:askInfo animated:YES];
```

In these situations, the modal opens just fine but the background of the modal is in portrait mode.

Any idea how I can ensure that all views in my app are always in landscape model with or without the modal?

Answer (score 0):

So I finally found out how to get it to work. Instead of opening the modal in the `viewDidLoad` method, I open it in `viewDidAppear`.